# Basic Rules of Probability

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Suppose I have two events $B$ and $A^c$ and I wish to compute the probability of their intersection.  I just want to ensure that the following proof holds (i.e., is correct -- I'm a little rusty).  **Updated!**  Assume the events are independent.

\begin{gather*}
P(A^c) = 1- P(A) \\
\end{gather*}
so
\begin{align*}
P(B \cap A^c) &= P(B) \times \Big(1-P(A)\Big) \\
&= P(B) - P(B)P(A) \\
&= P(B) - P(B \cap A)
\end{align*}

Another way to look at it, $A$ and $B$ are two events in some sample space $\mathcal{F}$, i.e., $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$.  This means:

\begin{align*}
B = (A\cap B) \cup (B\cap A^c)
\end{align*}

so

\begin{align*}
P(B) &= P(A\cap B) + P(B \cap A^c) \\
P(B \cap A^c) &= P(B) - P(A \cap B)
\end{align*}

Comment: Which probabilities are given to start with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not write $A^c = 1-A$ because these are events, not probabilities. So to prove that $P(B\cap A^c)=P(B)-P(B\cap A)$ you'll have to use different tactics. One of them is graphical - Venn diagrams. For analytical solution you can go the following way:

Recall that for two not mutually exclusive events we have:

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$

Then:

$$P(B \cap A^c) = P(A^c) + P(B) - P(A^c \cup B)$$

so you need to show that $P(A^c)-P(A^c \cup B)=P(A \cap B)$. This is true when you think about it, but can you show it why it is the case? Say, assume $x \in P(A \cap B)$. Could you show that $x$ also belongs to $P(A^c)-P(A^c \cup B)$? And if you assume that $x$ belongs to $P(A^c)-P(A^c \cup B)$. Could you show that it also belongs $P(A \cap B)$? Then you would be done. This could be achieved if you think about these events as sets.

Comment: Thanks Sarunas!  I've updated my question to reflect that I'm working with probabilities.  What do you think now?

Comment: now it seems coherent! good luck :)